# images won't draw on load in firefox, but do draw when there is a mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, fabricjs

I have an interesting bug which some of you might be familiar with (I hope).

I am drawing a bunch of pictures on a canvas and I allow the user to move these images around by drag and drop.

I have a function trial which is what gets called when the user presses a button to start a trial

```
function trial(){
    numImages   = objectIndices.length;
    checkObjectPositions = newFilledArray(numImages, 0);
    var initialPositions = [];        
    initialPositions = createCoords(numImages,initArrangementRad);        
    xpos = initialPositions.x;
    ypos = initialPositions.y;        
    canvas.clear().renderAll();        
    drawArena();
    drawObjects();
    canvas.getObjects();                        
    listenForEvents();
    canvas.renderAll();            
};
function drawObjects(){
        // load sprite with objects
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(objectImg) {
        // temp canvas to generate object images
        var tempCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
        // only to fit one object onto temp canvas
        tempCanvas.setDimensions({
          width: spriteWidth,
          height: spriteHeight
        });

        // make sure image is drawn from left/top corner
        objectImg.originX = 'left';
        objectImg.originY = 'top';
        // add it onto temp canvas
        tempCanvas.add(objectImg);
        for (var i=0;i<objectIndices.length;i++) {
            var posidx = i;                
            var indicetodraw = objectIndices[posidx];
            var object = createObject(posidx,indicetodraw, objectImg,tempCanvas);
        }
    });
};

function createObject(posidx,idx, objectImg, tempCanvas) {

    // offset object sprite to fit each of the objects onto it
    objectImg.left = -spriteWidth * idx;
    objectImg.setCoords();
    tempCanvas.renderAll();
    var posX = xpos[posidx]-(spriteWidth/2)*sizeOn;
    var posY = ypos[posidx]-(spriteHeight/2)*sizeOn;
    // get data url for that object
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = tempCanvas.toDataURL();

    // create image of an object from data url
    var oImg = new fabric.Image(img, {
      width: spriteWidth,
      height: spriteHeight,
      name:"object"+[idx],
      index: idx,
      originX:'left',
      originY:'top',
      left: posX,
      top: posY,
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false,
      lockRotation: true,
      lockUniScaling:true,
      scaleX: sizeOff,
      scaleY: sizeOff,
      hasControls: false
    });
    canvas.add(oImg);
    return oImg;
}
```

I want to spare you the details of the subfunctions for now, the essential bit is that when I call drawObjects() this draws a set of objects around a circular arena. When I run this in Chrome, there is no problem all images draw on load, however in firefox, nothing will draw until the user clicks somewhere in the div where the canvas exists. I tried simulating clicks in the trial() function but this does not resolve it, as this is not linked to clicking a button but anywhere inside the div (or canvas), and attaching a click function to a Div element does not do anything.

I am using fabric 1.4.9

any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

ian

Comment: Hard to tell from the code provided without more context on where this code is... my first guess is that you need to wrap your javascript with something like: `$(document).ready(function() { /* all your JS code here */ });`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree it is difficult to see without all of the code. I will try and create a jsfiddle replicating the bug when I have a bit of time. I tried wrapping the JS code with a document ready, but this did not resolve it, still need a click in firefox for the images to appear.